# Android FCM push notification icon not showing in oreo devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send push notification to the user. Notification icon shows when the app in the foreground, but when the app is in the background only white circle is showing. This problem exists only in oreo devices. Manifest file:-

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/notcolor" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="fcm_default_channel"/>
```

Comment: What is the file extension for ic_stat_name?

Comment: @HedShafran .png.

Comment: Thanks, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase showing success but not sending cloud messaging (Android - PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644167/firebase-showing-success-but-not-sending-cloud-messaging-android-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be using an outdated firebase messaging SDK (<12)

It has been fixed since 12.0.0

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0"
}
```

You can check the [release note](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

> Fixed a regression that caused custom notification icons to be
>   rejected on Android 8.0.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with FCM version 17.3.0.